# Alternatives to "this last point"

Tags: word-choice

What alternatives are there to the expression "this last point"? I'll give an example of a sentence that I wrote recently, referring to the Jane Austen novel Pride and Prejudice:

> The dialog and narration is written
>   with a fluency and accuracy that
>   allows Jane Austen to make remarkably
>   fine points. This last point is of
>   particular interest to me, as I often
>   find myself unable to convey the exact
>   meaning that I would wish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"This". as in "This is of particular interest to me".

Vigorous writing is concise...

Comment: +1. (Perhaps the full stop after ""this"" should be replaced by a comma.)

Answer (score 4):

I like simply "This," as suggested by Rob.

Also, when the preceding point is of some complexity, you can specify the point or points to which you are referring. For example, you could write "This accuracy is of particular…"

Comment: 'This' ^ :)  Pun intended!

Answer (score 0):

> **These fine points** are of particular interest to me, as I often find
>   myself unable to convey the exact meaning that I would wish.

Using '*this*' might work, but that would create a little ambiguity as to what 'this' is referring to:  Does '*this*' mean the dialog and narration itself, the fluency, or the fact that Jane Austen makes find points?